# Why aren't my reactive values initialised in the server function unique to each session?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm deploying my app to shinyapps and I'm noticing some strange behaviour when I have multiple windows open. I have rendered a datatable and when I update the filters on a window, my table only updates on the last window that was opened.

I have moved my reactive values to be loaded in the server function after reading the scoping documentation.

app.R

```
source("helpers/load_data.R")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

source("helpers/load_session_data.R")

output$risk_table <- renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(riskData$data
              rownames = FALSE)
})

observeEvent(input$get_filtered_data, {
    # UpdateTable function takes my table_csv and filters by the date, and updates the riskData reactive value
    UpdateTable(table, input$date)
}

UpdateTable <- function(table, date) {
#... filter stuff
riskData$data <- filtered_table
}
}
```

load_session_data.R

```
#table is a data.frame loaded globally outside of the ui and server functions.
riskData <- reactiveValues(data = table_csv)
```

I thought that loading my reactive values in the server function meant that each session would have it's own reactive values? I want to be able to filter a table independently in different sessions.

Comment: Is there a reason that `riskData` is being loaded globally? why not put it in the server function as well.

Comment: I thought it wasn't being loaded globally, it's in my load_session_data.R and I thought the object would be created in the server function `source("helpers/load_session_data.R")`

Comment: I was just reading you comment `#table is a data.frame loaded globally outside of the ui and server functions.`. I see that it is being sourced now.

Comment: The problem is you have not set `local=T`, the default being `FALSE` in the `source()` call. When local is set to F then the source call is shared across all sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things

1) Set `local=T` during source call

```
source("helpers/load_data.R", local=T)
source("helpers/load_session_data.R", local=T)
```

"If you use the default value of local = FALSE, then the file will be sourced in the global environment."

[Source](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html)

2) Put your source calls under the server function, otherwise even when enabling `local=T` the call will be shared across sessions

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
source("helpers/load_data.R", local=T)
source("helpers/load_session_data.R", local=
...
}
```

A really good example in the shiny docs.. (Code can be found [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html))

> ```
> # Objects in this file are shared across all sessions in the same R
> # process
> source('all_sessions.R', local = TRUE)
>
> server <- function(input, output, session) {
>   # Objects in this file are defined in each session
>   source('each_session.R', local = TRUE)
>
>   output$text <- renderText({
>     # Objects in this file are defined each time this function is called
>     source('each_call.R', local = TRUE)
>
>     # ...
>   })
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I did notice was that I couldn't update my reactive value within my `UpdateTable` function, so I returned my filtered table and updated the reactive value within the  `observeEvent(input$get_filtered_data...`

Comment: Is this because the reactive values were no longer in the global environment?

Comment: @Data_D Its hard to say without being able to test the program. My hunch is that your `UpdateTable` function is not a reactive environment so you would not be able to modify or create reactive varaibles/values. While the `observeEvent` is a reactive environment which allowed you to do so.